# Python send request with header

Tags: python, request, httplib

Sending Post request error

Hi talented developers. I am going to send request to specified url with authorization header. 
I am trying to send POST request to 
POST https://server/api HTTP 1.1
Authorization: Bearer a12b34567c89012def34g56789hi0j12
{
"data" : "test"
}

```
url = "https://server/api"
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % API_KEY}
data = {
    "data" : "test"
}
req = requests.post (url, headers = headers, data = 
json.dumps(data))
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong in this code snippet?
I appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you facing problems? Elaborate your problem

Comment: I called api and it send result with credential is incorrect, but I input correct api key.

Comment: That's why I want to know is there any issue in my code above?

Comment: Probably just a side issue, but if you're sending JSON, you should use `json=data` instead of `data=json.dumps(data)`.

Comment: Api call is failed at credential confirmation. Could you tell me about how can I send header with api key?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/85ipa57ukp2706e/Screenshot%20from%202019-09-17%2004-42-23.png?dl=0

Comment: I uploaded photo api call example

Comment: Could you tell me what is wrong in my code implementation?

Comment: Aside from the json parameter I mentioned, nothing seems wrong in the code.  If the API says that your credentials are wrong, then I would tend to believe it.  Are you sure the api key is correct?  Are you sure that `Bearer` is the correct authentication method?

Comment: Thanks John, Really appreciate your answer. I will try to get api credential correctly

Comment: add in question link to documentation for this API. Code seems OK but different API may need some other elements.

Comment: image with example request shows that it sends many information as JSON. And this can be your problem.  You sends only `"data" : "test"` and this can be not enought to get credential. ie. it may need `privateKey` for credential but other elements can be important too.

Comment: But as I wrote above, response says that credential is incorrect

Comment: What do you think about it Furas? Thanks for your help

Comment: credential can be incorrect because you don't have all values in `data`. It may need two values for credential - ie. `API KEY` and `Private Key` - similar like you need login and password to get access to some pages.